# MySQL select only one record from similar per day

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

I have table with users actions. One of them occurs every time when user opens certain page.

Table structure:
id, user_id, action_type, created_at...

I need to select from this table all actions per day/week... but without repeating of similar in one day. For example: user has visited 10 pages but 5 of them was the same. The result of selection should contain only unique pages per day.

Is it possible to do with only MySQL logic? Or better I should update repeated action if it occurs the same day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach uses `select distinct`:

```
select distinct user_id, action_type, date(created_at) created_date
from mytable
```

If needed, you can also count how many times each `action_type` was met on a `user_id` and day basis with aggregation:

```
select user_id, action_type, date(created_at) created_date, count(*) cnt
from mytable
group by user_id, action_type, date(created_at)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following SQL code :

```
SELECT DISTINCT URL 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY date;
```

I assume that your table name is `table_name`, you have the URLs (pages) in the column named `URL` and you you track the date in the column named `date`;